# Fluent: How to sort filtered entities by relevance?

Tags: swift, fluent, vapor

I was able to write a query that filters some Post objects by their title or body:

```
router.get("posts", "list") { req -> Future<[Post]> in 

    let searchText = req.query[String.self, at: "searchText"]!

    return Post.query(on: req).group(.or, closure: { query in
        query.filter(\Post.title ~~ searchText)
        query.filter(\Post.body ~~ searchText)
    })
}
```

It works, in the sense that I can verify that all the posts that don't contain the searchText parameter in their title or body are filtered out. Now for my next step, I would like to sort these results by their relevance.

Example data:
1) Title: "Hello, world!", body: "test msg".
2) Title: "Hello!", body: "..."
3) Title: "Hi", body: "!"

What I would like is to have an 'affinity search' query, such that the results are not strictly filtered, and they are ordered by relevance. So with the above data, if I search for the string "Hello!", I would like to get something like:
2) Title: "Hello!", body: "..."
1) Title: "Hello, world!", body: "test msg"

And the 3rd post would be filtered out from the search, because the relevance is not high enough. I understand that this is not really a deterministic, and well-specified problem. But I would like to understand if there is already something in fluent, and if not, what is a good approach to follow in order to solve this problem.

Comment: I'm not even sure you could do this with raw SQL. The metrics for 'relevance' are very arbitrary and unique to your application so you'd probably need to do this on the server rather than the database. (Another option would be to look at something like ElasticSearch that's more suited to this kind of thing)